# Spark structured streaming - 2 ReadStreams in one app

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to have two separate ReadStreams in one app? I'm trying to listen to two separate Kafka topics and do calculations based on both DataFrames.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply subscribe to multiple topics:

```
// Subscribe to multiple topics
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

Or, if you specifically want to use two separated `readStream` definitions within one app:

```
// read stream A
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]

// read stream B
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic2")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

Comment: of course this works fine. The hard part is that I am doing calculations on one topic based on the other.. yet there is no joinable relationship.

Comment: can you give more details of the structure of the events

Comment: sure one topic (we will call topic1) will be microbatch. Topic2, on the other hand, must be an unbounded view of all the data that has come into topic2. Topic2's dataframe will have several UDF's that do calculations that are based on both data frames. To accomplish this I used memsink for the topic2 dataframe. I don't think this is great but I can't see a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by using [`join()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins) in Spark 2.3.0:

```
val stream1 = spark.readStream. ...
val stream2 = spark.readStream. ...

val joinedDf = stream1.join(stream2, "join_column_id")
```

Comment: This assumes they have the same schema. I'm my case they don't and I simply want two separate updated streaming dataframes in the sane context.

Comment: It doesn't require to have the same schema except a column in each dataset to be used for joining. Moreover, you can specify any expression to be used for joining (see examples [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins)).

Could you please describe what exactly do you want to solve?

Comment: I'm running mathamatical calculations on components of both topics. One topic I want as an updated dataframe of everything consumed and the other is ephemeral and will be discarded after the calculations. The output will be produced to another kafka topic.

Comment: I don't think a join will work after some testing. the main reason why is the difference of rows in each dataframe. You could fill with na's or what I am testing is using Hive and have separate processes. There appears to be functionality to refresh tables so this may work well in my case.